# receive notification when current task ends

Tags: android

I'm writing an android app where I'd like to maintain the current location for the user while my app is open. I'm trying to figure out how to know when to stop listening for updates from my LocationManager, but can't seem to figure out a good way to know when the current task is paused.

Is there an easy way to say something like onTaskFinish() or onTaskPause()?

Comment: is there any condition for stop listening....?

Answer (score 1):

When the application is paused the method onPause() gets called.  That would be a good place to put it.  The corresponding method called when the activity resumes is onResume().